# Difference between using and .Dispose() call in C#

Tags: c#

I've been using Using lately but i wonder how it differs from calling .Dispose() explicitly. For instance what would be the difference between:

```
using (DisposableTest obj = new DisposableTest()) { /* Some code */ }
```

and

```
DisposableTest obj = new DisposableTest();
// Some code
obj.Dispose();
```

Assuming DisposableTest implements IDisposable ?

Comment: Question closed while answering with demonstration test codes. Duplicated topics cover your question with lots of answers and comments. Added my implementation to first one you can test it yourself

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They differ in a couple of ways:

1. `using` creates a new scope.
2. `using` calls `.Dispose()` regardless of how control leaves the block (if the object is not null at that point).  It would be the same as writing a `try`/`finally` construct that places "if not null then `.Dispose()`" in the `finally` block, but in a format that expresses the intent.

It exists so that if control leaves the block in any way (an exception occurs or a `return` or `break` is encountered), the `.Dispose()` is still called.  It is also more expressive because it better indicates the programmer's intent for this case than a generic `try`/`finally` construct.

Comment: Thanks that was so detailed and well explained. Didn't think of `return` and `break`

Comment: Updated the answer with a note on an implied null check.  If the object provided to the `using` block is null at the time control leaves the block, it won't try to call `.Dispose()` on it.

Answer (score 6):

The first version with the `using` keyword makes sure that `obj` is disposed even if the code in the middle throws an exception. It's like using a `try` `finally` block but less verbose.

Answer (score 4):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx):

> The using statement ensures that Dispose is called even if an
>   exception occurs while you are calling methods on the object. You can
>   achieve the same result by putting the object inside a try block and
>   then calling Dispose in a finally block; in fact, this is how the
>   using statement is translated by the compiler.

```
using (DisposableTest obj = new DisposableTest())
{
   // some code throwing exception here.
}
```

is equivalent to

```
{
   DisposableTest obj = new DisposableTest();
   try
   {
       // some code throwing exception here.
   }
   finally
   {
      obj.Dispose();
   }
}
```

**Note the extra curly braces to create the limited scope for the object**

Comment: Hm, unless I'm reading this wrong, if the `DisposableTest` constructor throws an exception, `obj` will be null in the finalizer and Dispose will throw an exception. As far as I remember, `using` won't dispose objects where the _constructor_ throws an exception. I think the constructor call should be outside the `try` block.

Comment: @Joachim - Yeah that's true. I have updated the answer. Hope it makes sense now.

Comment: Your code sample with the `try`-`finally`-block does not compile, as `obj` has gone out of scope at the end of the `try`-block and thus is not visible in the `finally`-block.

Comment: Rightly pointed out O.R.Mapper. Thanks.!!

Comment: @RohitVats Still, the constructor call should go _outside_ the try. If it throws an exception, the object should not be disposed. Only the code inside the `using` block should go inside the `try`.

Answer (score 4):

There is absolutely no difference in your code. However, if the body of the block is non-empty, there would be a significant difference:

```
using (DisposableTest obj = new DisposableTest()) {
    <some code here> // This code may throw an exception
}
```

vs.

```
DisposableTest obj = new DisposableTest();
<some code here> // Same code as above
obj.Dispose();
```

If `<some code here>` throws an exception, the `using` block will execute `obj.Dispose()`, while the code without `using` will skip the call of `obj.Dispose()`. That is why one should prefer `using` in situations when ensuring the cleanup is critical.

Comment: You are right, edited and added `// Some code` comment parts. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The difference is absent in fact. Using is more exceptions-safe: it does not skip execution, if it occurs. By the way, the third construction you can use is:

```
DisposableTest obj = null;
try
{
    obj = new DisposableTest();
}
catch(Exception e)
{
}
finally
{
    obj.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: The constructor call should go _outside_ the try block, only the code inside the `using` block should go inside the `try`.

Comment: Does `default(DisposableTest)` not return `null` ? and wouldn't an `NullReferenceException` occur?

Comment: @ElliotTereschuk thanks, i can't upvote your answer for now. Forgive

Comment: @metalmad Here is the previous variant. Does mentioning `NullReferenceException` make a sense?